# Algorithm for generating random regular graphs in Maple

Tags: math-software, maple

In Maples package **RandomGraphs**, there is a method called RandomRegularGraph(n,d) which takes a number of vertices $n$ and a degree $d$ and returns a random $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices. Does anybody know how this random regular graph is sampled, and if it is in fact uniformly chosen from all $d$-regular graphs on $n$ vertices?

Answer (score 0):

That method is most likely based on these random regular graph generation papers:

```
.. [1] A. Steger and N. Wormald,
   Generating random regular graphs quickly,
   Probability and Computing 8 (1999), 377-396, 1999.
   http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/steger99generating.html

.. [2] Jeong Han Kim and Van H. Vu,
   Generating random regular graphs,
   Proceedings of the thirty-fifth ACM symposium on Theory of computing,
   San Diego, CA, USA, pp 213--222, 2003.
   http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=780542.780576
```

For reference, you can find a python implementation of a `random_regular_graph` method [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/e9506c80ee25a101f2dcd7b8784eabac87b3a486/networkx/generators/random_graphs.py).